# When do we need nonlocal in a higher order function?

Tags: python

The following code #1 requires `nonlocal previous_score`

```
def announce_max(previous_score = 0):
    """
    print the max of all scores
    >>> f0 = announce_max()
    >>> f1 = f0(5)
    5
    >>> f2 = f1(2)
    5
    >>> f3 = f2(3)
    5
    >>> f4 = f3(7)
    7
    """
    def say(current_score):
        nonlocal previous_score
        previous_score = max(previous_score, current_score)
        print(previous_score)
        return announce_max(previous_score)
    return say
```

The following code #2 does NOT require `nonlocal previous_score`

```
def announce_max(previous_score = 0):
    """
    print the max of all scores
    >>> f0 = announce_max()
    >>> f1 = f0(5)
    5
    >>> f2 = f1(2)
    5
    >>> f3 = f2(3)
    5
    >>> f4 = f3(7)
    7
    """
    def say(current_score):
        # nonlocal previous_score
        print(max(previous_score, current_score))
        return announce_max(max(previous_score, current_score))
    return say
```

Why do we need `nonlocal previous_score` in code #1 above, do we call it outside the function `say`?

If yes, why code #2 works?

Comment: tl;dr: By default, Python creates a local variable when (and only when) an *assignment* to a name appears in a function. `nonlocal` overrides that default.

Comment: (this was closed pointing to a duplicate which dealt with global variables - that is far from the non-local variable case analyzed here. There may be closer q/a's around to mark this as duplicate, but them, as the question title differs, it may be worth to just answer it here.)

Comment: @jsbueno: That said, the rules for when `nonlocal` is needed are *identical* to the rules when you need `global`, so knowing the rules for the latter and the overlap of the rules does answer the question.

Comment: but then, the question is specific about "nonlocal"; clearly not a duplicate (to that specific question). It is easier to write a paragraph here and link other relevant answers in the text, if they will aggregate value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need it when you assign to the name, and want to change the closure scoped variable. The act of assignment is what makes a name a local in a function (and it is a local from the beginning of the function, it doesn't switch roles at the moment of assignment); `nonlocal` and `global` declarations are what undoes that automatic creation of a local name.

So long as you don't assign to it, reading from that name invokes LEGB lookup, logically checking the local scope first, then enclosing scope(s), then global, then built-in scope. In practice, a name's presence in local or enclosing scopes is statically determined, so at most two scopes are ever checked (when it's not local or enclosing, it checks the global scope first, and falls back to built-in scope if a name being read is not in global scope).

Answer (score 0):

The second version of your function do not work as intended - it will not update the maximum previous score as in the first function.

What is relevant is: outter-scope variables are always *readable* from nested functions, but they cannot be updated.

If your second function would try to update `previous_score` without the non local declaration, the function would error with NameError in the line you try to read the value in `previous_score` to calculate the `max`. That is: if the name is written to in the nested function, Python assumes it to be local to the function, unless it is explicitly declared as nonlocal or as global. In that case, in the following code, the `previous_score` local to `say` would not be assigned when calling `max`:

```
# this is broken:
def announce_max(previous_score = 0):
   
    def say(current_score):
   
        previous_score = max(previous_score, current_score)
        print(previous_score)
        return announce_max(previous_score)
    return say
```